# .phar file in root crontab will not fire, works OK as sudo

Tags: cron

I have a PHPBU job scheduled in my root crontab:

```
6 * * * * /etc/phpbu/phpbu.phar --configuration=/var/www/vhosts/example.com/backups/example.com-phpbu-config-hourly.xml
```

If I `sudo` the command (minus the `6 * * * *` as a `sudo`-able user, the task runs, performs a backup, and exits as expected, no errors. The config is valid, the `phpbu.phar` file is `root:root` with `775`.

When the crontab fires (6 minutes past the hour), nothing happens. If I update the crontab entry to append to a text file…:

```
6 * * * * /etc/phpbu/phpbu.phar --configuration=/var/www/vhosts/example.com/backups/example.com-phpbu-config-hourly.xml >>/tmp/phpbu-crontab.txt
```

…a zero byte file is created. If I top and tail with something to test if root crontab is running, and make the `.phar` run more often…:

```
* * * * * touch /tmp/hello
* * * * * /etc/phpbu/phpbu.phar --configuration=/var/www/vhosts/example.com/backups/example.com-phpbu-config-hourly.xml >>/tmp/phpbu-crontab.txt
* * * * * touch /tmp/goodbye
```

…I get `/tmp/hello`, `/tmp/goodbye` with an updated timestamp every minute (expected) and nothing in `/tmp/phpbu-crontab.txt` at all. No errors.

I am stumped. I would be very grateful for some pointers or additional things to check.

Thank you in advance for any advice or feedback.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved. I needed to prepend the PHP-CLI:

```
* * * * * /path/to/php-cli /etc/phpbu/phpbu.phar --configuration=/var/www/vhosts/example.com/backups/example.com-phpbu-config-hourly.xml
```